# Parsing a nested JSON as a dictionary with Swift / SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm using SwiftyJSON to parse a nested JSON. The JSON is used to populate a form where the user is shown the "keys" from the JSON to select from and then the corresponding values to the selection are used to calculate a score.

I've tried to parse the JSON and the parsing works well to get the rest of the data (e.g. the question) but when I try to parse the portion of the JSON where the scores (key: values) are, I get null.

```
{
        "Question": "Pick a Number from the given values",
        "Answer_Choices": { 
                 "10": "6",
                  "9": "6",
                  "8": "3",
                  "7": "3",
                  "6": "1"
        }

}
```

In the above code I want to display the left numbers to the user where they pick the 'keys' and correspondingly I will assign the values the values to contribute to the user's score, e.g. if the user selects 8, I'll assign them 3. I'm not sure how I can cast the key as well as values dynamically. They always fill up as null.

Question is parsed as:

```
var question = JSON["Question"].string 
var answerChoices = JSON["Answer_Choices"].dictionaryObject // I know this is probably not correct.
```

Comment: How would that give me the list of keys and values dynamically

Comment: I tried it and the warning I get is the cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[String: String]' always fails

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. Here is how you can parse to get separate arrays for answers and points

```
    guard let dict = json["Answer_Choices"].dictionaryObject as? [String:String] else {
        return
    }
    let answerArray = Array(dict.keys)
    let pointsArray = Array(dict.values)
```